# Why does my neural network only work with a subset of my data

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, data-science

Currently I am working on a project with the FIFA 19 dataset from Kaggle and I am classifying whether any given player is a field player or a goal keeper. The dataset is order from top players to the worst players. I created a simple neural network with 2 relu layers and 1 sigmoid layer and when all the data is plugged in the accuracy is almost 0, and the loss is NaN. I noticed when I used a subset of the data and kept it ordered I easily got an accuracy of 1. But when the subset of data that is unordered(shuffled) it once again gets an accuracy of 0 and loss of NaN. Technically I got it to work with the small subset of ordered data, but I'm confused why it would not work with all the data shuffled, or a small subset shuffled. I using highly polarized features such as goal keeper reflexes and kicking so I would expect it to be a simple task of distinguishing between the two classes. Thanks in advance,
Noah

Comment: My guess is that there is either something wrong with your code or with your dataset; but I can't see either so it's a bit hard to tell.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel is probably right. from my experience when you get Nan in loss that means your loss function is having a problem calculating its value. this can be due to bug in loss function (if you are using a costom one) or your labels are not right. I would recommend to be sure that there is no bad numbers in your labels and that they are in the right format based on the API you are using and your last activation function.